# Can we dynamically change whole app language in flutter?

Tags: flutter, localization, internationalization, translation, language-translation

I want my **flutter application** to be in **French** `fr` language. Yes, we can define translations file & manually do all the translations of the app texts & then translate them based on the locale..

But the issue is that the text is coming from **firebase** (which is added to firebase from dashboard) & it will contain **text that isn't already defined in our translations file**. so what do we do here ?

Is there anything in **flutter** to tackle this issue ? IF **yes** what is it ? IF **NO** what are the alternatives in this case, if any..

**Thank You!!**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You need to use a Provider with a Model that implements a ChangeNotifier and use the package intl to provide the translated text that will be showed.
And finally, when you want to put a text in your program, you don't hardcode it but you call a function like this `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.youreright` to show the text, and it will be translated based on the data stored in yout model provider and the text that you wrote in the .arb file.
It's a lot to explain here, i'll put some links that explain better.

https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization

https://phrase.com/blog/posts/flutter-localization/

Comment: As i have mentioned in my question that:
```Yes, we can define translation files (arb etc) & manually do all the translations of the app texts & then translate them based on the locale..```

But what about the dynamic text that comes to the app from backend ?? that's what my query is.